# How can I get the string between two tags

Tags: c#, regex, strip

I wonder how to get a string (or array of strings) between two known tags.
For example I have this string

```
string var1="my first video is [video]http://video.com/aaa[/video] and my second is[video id=\"1\" length=\"3\"]http://video.com/bbb[/video]";
```

How to get these values `http://video.com/aaa` and `http://video.com/bbb`?

Comment: use regex [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression]

Comment: You don't even need Regex for this.

Comment: This question is far too vague.  You need to show some work.  What code have you tried?  What research have you done.  It will be closed otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this pattern: `@"\[video.*?\](.*?)\[/video\]"` and then get group 1. I won't post the whole code because I dont want to do your work for you. Read about C# Regexes, Patterns and try to write your code with this pattern.

Comment: Thanks. I get it, using match with your pattern.